# Confusion validating XML against XSD with imports

Tags: xml, validation, coldfusion, xsd

Thank you in advance for any assistance provided.  I am attempting to validate an XML against an XSD that is importing another XSD.  As simple as this sounds I am experiencing an interesting error that does not make sense to me.

The XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tt:TroubleTicket xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tt="http://metadata.dod.mil/mdr/ns/netops/shared_data/trouble_ticket/0.4" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://metadata.dod.mil/mdr/ns/netops/shared_data/trouble_ticket/0.4 newSchemas/trouble_ticket.xsd">

<tt:troubleTicketID>
<!-- all child nodes -->
</tt:troubleTicketID>
</tt:TroubleTicket>
```

The Main XSD (trouble_ticket.xsd):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http:/ww.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
targetNamespace="http://metadata.dod.mil/mdr/ns/netops/shared_data/trouble_ticket/0.4"    
xmlns:tt="http://metadata.dod.mil/mdr/ns/netops/shared_data/trouble_ticket/0.4" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://metadata.dod.mil/mdr/ns/netops/shared_data/trouble_ticket/0.4 newSchemas/trouble_ticket.xsd"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:import namespace="http://metadata.dod.mil/mdr/ns/netops/net_defense/cnd-core/0.4" schemaLocation="cnd-core.xsd"/>

<!-- element declarations, simple and complex definitions -->
```

The imported XSD (cnd-core.xsd):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://metadata.dod.mil/mdr/ns/netops/net_defense/cnd-core/0.4"    
xmlns:cndc="http://metadata.dod.mil/mdr/ns/netops/net_defense/cnd-core/0.4" 
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<!-- element declarations, simple and complex definitions -->
```

```
And finally the error that is generating when I attempt a validation:
```

```html
[Error] :9:39: src-import.3.1: The namespace attribute, "http://metadata.dod.mil/mdr/ns/netops/net_defense/cnd-core/0.4" of an import element information item must be identical to the targetNamespace attribute, "http://metadata.dod.mil/mdr/ns/netops/shared_data/trouble_ticket/0.4", of the imported document.
```

So, I am guessing this deals with the attempted import of cnd-core.xsd into trouble_ticket.xsd.  From what I can see, the namespace attribute of the import element (in trouble_ticket.xsd) DOES match the targetNamespace attribute of the document being imported (cnd-core.xsd).  The targetNamespace attribute of the imported document is not what the error says it is.  I am confused as to why the error shows the targetNamespace attribute to be different.

I have followed along with so many tutorials and publications to make sure I am setting these up correctly, but there must be something that I am missing.  Any insight will be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: It might be some kind of operational issue, so tell us what schema processor you are using, how you are invoking it, and where the relevant files are located.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael.  I am using ColdFusion, which as you may know is a tag-based convenience language for Java.  There is a built-in function called XmlValidate().  The files are all located in a dev environment all in the same folder.

Comment: `<cfset myResult = #XmlValidate("myxmlfile.xml", "myxsdfile.xsd")#>`

Comment: Thanks. Can't help you with ColdFusion, I'm afraid.